# Склонение слов, заимствованных из арабского

Tags: склонение

Добрый день! Столкнулась с такой проблемой при проверке диплома по исламским финансам. Автор использует такие термины, как сукук, мурабаха, мудараба, иджара, истисна, амана, закят. Но по тексту видно, что он не определился, склонять их или нет, поэтому в работе эти слова использованы, как в несклоняемой форме (например, на основании иджара), так и в соответствующем падеже (уплата закята). Я посмотрела источники на русском языке, в них тоже нет определенности. Видимо, каждый автор решает сам. Но мне хотелось бы, чтобы и правила русского языка были соблюдены. На мой взгляд, склонять нужно, т. к. текст воспринимается легче. А как вы считаете?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русском языке есть "правило" склонять всё, кроме тех слов, где склонение невозможно по грамматическим или историческим причинам. Последних очень немного, буквально единицы, в основном это слова, пока не освоенные языком, например, слова грамматический род или число которых отличается от определяемых по формальным признакам.

Почему для арабских слов надо делать какое-то исключение - совершенно непонятно. Замечено, правда, что авторы, профессионально относящиеся к какой-то замкнутой группе, тяготеют к несклонению слов из собственного профессионального арго. Но это никак нельзя признать нормативным.

В конце концов есть орфоэпические и  грамматические словари. Все т. н. "несклоняемые" слова имеют отметку "нескл.", если её нет, значит слово склоняется.

> Автор использует такие термины, как сукук, мурабаха, мудараба, иджара, истисна, амана, закят.

Не вижу никаких причин сомневаться в нормативной склоняемости этих слов. Все слова мне более или менее знакомы, Не помню, чтобы в ранее читаных мною текстах кто-то отказывался от их склонения.

> На мой взгляд, склонять нужно, т.к. текст воспринимается легче. А как вы считаете?

Склонять нужно, но аргумент ваш субъективен и слаб. Кому-то легче, кому-то нет. Склонять нужно просто потому, что иное противоречит и писаным и неписаным правилам русского языка.

> на основании иджара

А точно здесь не склоняется? 
Иджар - слово мужского рода, фиксируется некоторыми словарями с вариантом "иджара" (именительный падеж), но он тоже склоняется. Или это еще какой-то термин? Сомнительно...

Comment: Спасибо за мнение. А какими словарями вы пользовались? В словарях на сайте грамота.ру этих слов нет. В литературе по исламским финансам (не во всей) эти слова не склоняются, если перед ними используются слова типа "договор", "инструмент". Какого рода иджара сказать не могу, но варианта иджар я не встречала. В книгах иджару склоняют по первому склонению (школьному). Кстати, нашла, что сукук - это множественное число. Но какого рода пока не ясно.

Comment: Честно говоря, в словаре посмотрел только "иджар", убедился что оно действительно имеет вариант "иджара", в чем я совсем не был уверен. Остальное мне знакомо.  А про Иджар есть даже в вики. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%80   Хороший словарь исламских терминов есть тут. http://slovar-islam.ru/books/a.html Но он не орфоэпический.

Comment: Ну и совсем кратенький http://islamic-finance.ru/load/1-1-0-1

Comment: *что сукук - это множественное число.* - В ***русском*** - это мужской род единственного. Хотя согласен, в данном случае возникает некоторая согласовательная трудность. Единственное в арабском - "сакк", но как термин последнее не используется. Поэтому нет причин отказываться от мужского рода единственного числа для "сукук" в русском.

Comment: Спасибо. Решила, что буду склонять.

Comment: Не знаю, как с арабским языком, но несклонение японских имён собственных имеет серьёзные причины.  Если склонять слова по "нормативным" правилам, то "мэр Осаки" - это мэр какого города?  Город Осака, префектура Осака, или город Осаки, префектура Мияги?  И таких случаев в японском языке множество.

Comment: @user31264, А мэр Иванова - это г. Иванов или г. Иваново? Или вообще фамилия? И откуда я знаю, что мер Осаки - это мер г. Осаки, которую кому-то лениво склонять, а не г. Осака из Осаки? Если у человека проблемы с георафией, то создание другим  искусственных проблем с русским ни ему, ни другим не помогут.  давайте тогда и Москву не склонять, чтоб её чем-нибудь не спутали.

Comment: Я могу еще понять (хотя и не поддердать) идею не склонять короткие имена собственные, в один слог, типа Ба, Ко и проч. Но Осаку-то за что?

Comment: г. Осаки, вопреки тому, что вы пишете, в принципе не склоняется.  (Как будет Осаки в родительном падеже?)  Москва тем и хороша, что городов "Москву", "Москве" и т. д. нет (и то же верно для других русских городов, пможет, за крайне редким исключением, отому что имена им придумывали носители русского языка).

Comment: ***Осака склоняется***. По правилам русского языка. Склоняется вообще все, что можно склонять по грамматике. Исключений очень немного. Из городов я могу вспомнить только  Осло. И не надо мне ничего делать "вопреки". Нормативный источник - в студию, тогда разговор будет иметь хоть какой-то смысл. А ваши рассуждения - не более чем личное мнение, даже не  авторитетное.  Вот и словарь предлагает склонять: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x

Comment: Кстати, полемика в комментариях здесь не приветствуется. Если хотите задать вопрос, задайте в отдельной теме.

Comment: Я нашла пример употребления в единственном числе слова, заимствованного в форме множественного числа, - бифштекс. Так что ваша позиция об употреблении слова "сукук" в м.р. и ед. ч. подтвердилась. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: *Я нашла пример употребления в единственном числе слова,* - а зачем искать было? Таких слов предостаточно: рельс, памперс, дата (ед. datum) и проч.

Comment: Чтобы студенту объяснить и привести пример. Насчет рельсов соглашусь. А дата и памперс заимствованы по-другому. Дата - от глагола dare. А памперс - это товарный знак на основе глагола pamper.

Comment: насчет даты - могу уточнить, не думаю, что принципиально. Насчет товарного знака - сомневаюсь, что это что-то объясняет или опровергает. Речь о том, что в английском памперс - множестенное число существительного. Точно так же джинсы - от английского, которое и без того множественное.    Русский язык приспосабливает под себя . (+) я не знал, что вы РКИ преподаете, это отдельная тема, тут я не силен в плане убедительных обоснований, так что "умываю руки"